# Why extract sample from wav file using udacity gui and scipy give different values?

Tags: python, audio, scipy, wav, audacity

I have an audio wav file of 7seconds: full.wav.

I extract a small sample of it. I select the timeframe using audacity and I label it. I export the label (containing start and end time of the sample).

1/ I export the sample using audacity menu and save it as sample_audacity.wav

2/ I load in a python script the full.wav using scipy.io.wavfile.read
I save the sample full[start:end]. It gives me sample_python.wav

**When I listen to sample_audacity.wav and sample_python.wav I hear the same.**

But if I load both of them using scipy.io.wavfile.read I got very different values for the 2 files.
the values of sample_python.wav are subset of the values of full.wav - which is normal.

But the values of sample_audacity.wav are not.

Does someone know why/how audacity is modifying the initial data (full.wav) when saving an extract of it?

And if possible how to get audacity to give me as sample that will have same values (subset) of the initial data?

As an example, the first 100 values of sample_audacity.wav

`[128 122 124 123 134 138 143 142 139 135 144 149 155 156 148 144 143 144
 151 152 159 152 160 150 157 151 155 153 155 156 154 151 145 139 128 132
 124 131 130 129 123 115 104 100  94  94  88  85  78  74  65  59  52  48
  43  45  46  45  40  30  19  10   6   7  14  15  12   0  -8   1  23  51
  72  63  55  26  23  20  31  36  40  35  27  22  15  15   7   9   1  -2
  -4   0  -3  -4 -18 -25 -25 -12  -1  -9]`

Shape of sample_audacity.wav: 
(36296,)

the first 100 values of  sample_python.wav

`[128 127 124 122 125 132 139 143 142 138 137 142 150 155 155 149 144 142
 145 150 154 156 156 155 155 154 153 153 154 155 156 154 151 145 138 131
 128 127 129 131 129 123 114 105  99  95  93  89  84  79  73  66  59  52
  47  44  45  46  45  39  31  19  10   5   8  13  16  11   0  -7   0  23
  52  69  68  50  30  20  22  30  37  39  35  28  21  16  13  10   7   2
  -3  -3  -1  -1  -6 -17 -26 -24 -12  -2]`

Shape of sample_python.wav: 
(36297,)

Audacity 2.1.2
Ubuntu

Preferences import/export: 
[image]

Export settings:
[image]

Media info for both files: 
[image]

Comment: Sampling rate and depth are the same on both tools?

Comment: Yes. Depth is 16bits in both, and the sample is selected manually via Audacity. I export the labels corresponding to the selection - so exactly the same start and end timestamp as when I export via Audacity interface. 

I updated the post with mediainfo outputs for both files

Files are available here https://files.fm/u/mrq2zjgf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the file is imported into audacity, it is converted to 32-bit format. When you re-export the file back to 16-bits, audacity will dither the audio according to the preferences. There are more details on this page: https://wiki.audacityteam.org/wiki/Dither

This export setting is not in an obvious location. Go to Preferences/Quality and then Dither under the "High Quality Conversion" heading. If you set this to None you should get the same results as python.

Comment: Cool! Unfortunately I can not test it until next sunday - but as soon as I get my ubuntu back I will. Thank you :)

Comment: Yep! I also changed the other parameters I found in the "quality" setting (set the default sampling rate to 48KHz and Default sample format to 16bits - that was the values for my input values) - And then indeed, the cut exported from the interface was subset of the intital values. Thanks @jaket